# Spring boot logging.file.max-size not working

Tags: spring-boot

I've following configuration in Spring boot application.properties file. The log is getting generated but not rolling after 1 MB.

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.file=C:/logs/Application.log
logging.file.max-size=1MB
logging.file.max-history=10
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=Application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
```

Comment: if you set logging.file.max-history=0(# Maximum of archive log files to keep. Only supported with the default logback setup.) it will start rolling after 1MB

Answer (score 0):

I test on my local and found rolling file is made at application running directory.
So I think following will work as expected.

```
logging.file.name=C:/logs/Application.log
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=C:/logs/Application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
```

I tested with spring-boot version 2.4.1

Comment: It did not work for me. I'm using Spring boot 2.2.1. For Spring boot 2.4 it requires Gradle 5.x+ but our organization permits only for Gradle 4.x

Comment: I tested with version 2.2.1.RELEASE but it can work as well .

Comment: Thanks for trying @rakuraku .I've updated my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after commenting below lines. Earlier I used log4j2 so for that I had to exclude default logging provided by spring-boot. In order to use logback we need to make sure spring-boot-starter-logging is enabled.

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
```